# IOStream writing data to console

Tags: java

I have read that only lower order 8 bits are used while Output of byte output stream, then why I am getting 5?
Also, why I am not getting the binary or hex format of 65?

If I delete the leading 2 zeros and make the value of b as 65 then I get 'A' as the answer but why by placing leading 2 zeros I am not getting the answer but '5'?

Also why I am getting the answer as a character and not in binary format as 'out' is a `Byte OutputStream` object and should write in bytes?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int b = 0065;
        System.out.write(b);
        System.out.flush();

    }
```

desired 'A', actual 5?

Also, desired `0100 0001`.

Answer (score 0):

Static field `out` in class `java.lang.System` has type `java.io.PrintStream`. 
 Class `PrintStream` has several `write()` methods.  In your code, the argument you are passing to method `write()` is an `int`, hence the method invokde is `write(int)`.  You are assigning a number literal to your local variable `b`.  In java, a number literal that begins with a zero (0) indicates an octal number and *65* in octal is 53 (fifty-three) in decimal and 53 is the ASCII code for the digit 5 (five).  For your information, class `java.lang.Integer` has static method `toBinaryString()`.  I suggest you look at the javadoc for that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StackOverFlow{

 public static void main(String []args){

    int x = 0065;// in java when you append zero like 011 or 0023 its take as octal number,when you print it will convert to decimal

System.out.println(x); // 0065 is octal value when you convert to decimal it will be 53 and in hexa 35

int y = 056;//octal value

System.out.println(y); // Output:46 decimal value



 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `0065` is octal for decimal `53` for hexadecimal `0x35` for the ASCII character `5`.